# Rails logger reporting zero rendering and ActiveRecord time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have Rails logger in development environment reporting a zero view and activerecord performance time (development.log, console)

`Completed 200 OK in -558254026ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

It is not the case in other environments.

Any clues where I should be looking?

WinXP, Rails 3.1, JRuby 1.5.2, will_paginate, jruby-openssl, haml, haml-rails, transitions, rails-settings, fastercsv, rufus-scheduler, mongrel, timecop

Comment: If that time is accurate, the page was rendered almost 6.4 days before you made the request. That's pretty fast.

Comment: :) true - I've written this comment before writing my post too.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - I've got it. It was the timecop gem. I'm using it to allow the user to change the current time in development mode (along with a session cookie). Once I deleted the cookie (to readjust to the real current time), the log files started their proper time reporting.

I'll probably leave this here for some ideas on what could go wrong.